# Sort MySQL data by custom rule

Tags: mysql, sorting

I know MySQL support sort data by desc or asc, but use default sort rule cannot meet my requirement.

Can anyone have idea to sort the data like below in MySQL:

```
| agr_offer_inst                  |
| agr_offer_inst_22_00            |
| agr_offer_inst_22_00_err        |
| agr_offer_inst_22_01            |
| agr_offer_inst_22_01_err        |
| agr_offer_inst_22_02            |
| agr_offer_inst_22_02_err        |
| agr_offer_inst_22_03            |
| agr_offer_inst_22_03_err        |
| agr_offer_inst_22_04            |
| agr_offer_inst_22_04_err        |
| agr_offer_inst_22_05            |
| agr_offer_inst_22_05_err        |
| agr_offer_inst_22_06            |
| agr_offer_inst_22_06_err        |
| agr_offer_inst_22_07            |
| agr_offer_inst_22_07_err        |
| agr_offer_inst_22_08            |
| agr_offer_inst_22_08_err        |
| agr_offer_inst_22_09            |
| agr_offer_inst_22_09_err        |
| agr_offer_inst_err              |
| agr_offer_inst_h                |
| agr_offer_inst_h_22_00          |
| agr_offer_inst_h_22_01          |
| agr_offer_inst_h_22_02          |
| agr_offer_inst_h_22_03          |
| agr_offer_inst_h_22_04          |
| agr_offer_inst_h_22_05          |
| agr_offer_inst_h_22_06          |
| agr_offer_inst_h_22_07          |
| agr_offer_inst_h_22_08          |
| agr_offer_inst_h_22_09          |
```

The following is the result I need:

```
| agr_offer_inst                  |
| agr_offer_inst_22_00            |
| agr_offer_inst_22_01            |
| agr_offer_inst_22_02            |
| agr_offer_inst_22_03            |
| agr_offer_inst_22_04            |
| agr_offer_inst_22_05            |
| agr_offer_inst_22_06            |
| agr_offer_inst_22_07            |
| agr_offer_inst_22_08            |
| agr_offer_inst_22_09            |
| agr_offer_inst_err              |
| agr_offer_inst_22_00_err        |
| agr_offer_inst_22_01_err        |
| agr_offer_inst_22_02_err        |
| agr_offer_inst_22_03_err        |
| agr_offer_inst_22_04_err        |
| agr_offer_inst_22_05_err        |
| agr_offer_inst_22_06_err        |
| agr_offer_inst_22_07_err        |
| agr_offer_inst_22_08_err        |
| agr_offer_inst_22_09_err        |
| agr_offer_inst_h                |
| agr_offer_inst_h_22_00          |
| agr_offer_inst_h_22_01          |
| agr_offer_inst_h_22_02          |
| agr_offer_inst_h_22_03          |
| agr_offer_inst_h_22_04          |
| agr_offer_inst_h_22_05          |
| agr_offer_inst_h_22_06          |
| agr_offer_inst_h_22_07          |
| agr_offer_inst_h_22_08          |
| agr_offer_inst_h_22_09          |
```

I have try many times, but have no result.

Answer (score 1):

The `order by` can take multiple keys.  So, here is one method:

```
order by (case when col like '%\_h\_%' then 3
               when col like '%\_err' then 2
               else 1
          end),
         col
```

Comment: I only have one column and only the table end with `_err` need special deal with. I see your mean that sort by multiple keys according the first column. but thanks anyway!